# Why am I getting the missing comma error with this code

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out where the missing/extra comma is.

```
guilds = []

guildinfo = {'name': 'TestGuild', 'gp': '49710066'}

guilds.append({'GGp' : guildinfo{'gp'}, 'GName' : guildinfo{'name'}})
```

Comment: `guildinfo['gp']` and `guildinfo['name']`. Square brackets are used to access members of a `dict`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it would be obvious but that comes from being a noob. My background is perl.

Answer (score 0):

```
guilds = []

guildinfo = {'name': 'TestGuild', 'gp': '49710066'}

guilds.append([guildinfo['gp'],guildinfo['name']])
```

Your question doesn't specifies what you want to do exactly but here's working code with foolowing output:

```
print(guilds)
[['49710066', 'TestGuild']]
```